# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/user/Desktop/esample/react-minting-website/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

Tags: web3js, nodejs, react, web3-providers

[image]
[image: Here is the new error after changing react script version]

I am building a development web 3 project and can't figure out why I get this error

```
WARNING in src/App.js
  Line 2:10:  'useWeb3React' is defined but never used            no-unused-vars
  Line 4:8:   'web3' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
  Line 6:7:   'WalletConnect' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/user/Desktop/esample/react-minting-website/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

[image]

I attach both images. How do I solve this error? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Moralis forum, I think this may help you - https://forum.moralis.io/t/solved-breaking-change-webpack-5-used-to-include-polyfills-for-node-js-core-modules-by-default/6875

Comment: Thank i recompiled with the some corrections i saw on the forum but i got the following error

Comment: Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app /Users/user/Desktop/esample/react-minting-website/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js" and "BaseConfig » /Users/user/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js".                                                                                                              Any idea on how to solve this please Thanks  I have also attacked an image of the following error with package.json